# Calling a method / interface

Tags: c#

From Visual Studio I imported a WSDL via the Service References tool. From the methodsin the WSDL I need to call a method GetSessionID. The method is part of an Interface IdoSession. When I try to reference it in C# the compiler keeps telling me I am doing it wrong. What would be the correct syntax to call the GetSessionID method?

[image: View of the Object Browser]

If I use this code

```
    SSISSoapTester.IdoSession.IdoSession getID;
    idResponse = getID.GetSessionID(idRequest);
```

The compiler tells me "Use of unassigned local varible 'getID'

If I use this code

```
    SSISSoapTester.IdoSession.IdoSession getID;
    getID = new SSISSoapTester.IdoSession.IdoSession();
    idResponse = getID.GetSessionID(idRequest);
```

The compiler tells me "Cannot create an instance of the abstract calls or interface"

Granted this error makes sense to me because an interface is not a class.

Comment: Please post your code, not just a picture of the debugger.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? What does the compiler say? How do you reference it right now?

Comment: What is the exact message the compiler is giving you?  What code are you trying to use to call the method?

Comment: You can't invoke a interface's method, you have to invoke the method on a class that implements it. It looks like it asking you to supply GetSessionID with a type that implements IdoSession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell based on what you posted (please post actual code in the future), but I am guess ing that `IdoSessionClient` implements the `IdoSession` interface, which is what you have selected in your screenshot. In that case, you probably want to do something similar to:

```
GetSessionIdRequest request = new GetSessionIdRequest();
IdoSession client = new IdoSessionClient();
client.GetSessionId(request);
```

Comment: This worked!  It did not dawn on me to look at IdoSessionClient.  When I did it had what I needed.  Thanks for pointing that out to me.